# Trying to run a SQL query with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am new to Python and I tried connecting to my SQL Server database
using SQLAlchemy.

Here is the code:

Librairies:

```
import create_engine
import pandas as pd
```

Establishing connection with SQL Server:

```
Server='csi-07'
Database='SSO_WS_VF'
Driver= 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'
username = 'sa'
password = '*********.'
database_connection = f'mssql://{username}:{password}@{Server}/{Database}?driver={Driver}'
```

```
engine = create_engine(database_connection)
connection = engine.connect()
```

The SQL query:

```
data = pd.random('select * from [SSO_WS_VF].[dbo].[FACT_INVENTORY_ACTUAL]', connection)
```

and I am getting this error:

> module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_sql_query'

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please show docs for `pandas.random`. I cannot find this method.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is just `pd.read_sql ` my friend.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html